# Handling development env variables when using foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, configuration, foreman, env

When using the foreman gem, I include a .env file to specify different environment variables for my development environment.

However, when collaborating with other developers on a project, what is a good way to keep our .env files in sync with each other without checking credentials from services like Twilio and Pusher into source control?

At the moment, I keep an updated README.md at the root that specifies which keys we need, but it is extra work to have to look at the readme on every pull.

Answer (score 0):

We (I didn't come up with this, but my team has been using it for a while now) have an `env` subdirectory that's in the directory we run foreman from.  In env, there are files like `DATABASE_URI` or `MY_ENV_KEY` or whatever else you need, the values of which are the values that environment variable should be set to.

Then we have a script called `start_server.sh` which we call from Foreman's procfile:

```
#!/bin/bash

for env_file in `pwd`/env/*;
do
    name_of_var=`basename $env_file`
    get_val_of_var_cmd='echo "$'$name_of_var'"'
    val_of_var=`eval "$get_val_of_var_cmd"`

    if [[ "$val_of_var" == "" ]];
    then
    val_of_var=`cat $env_file`
    cmd="export $name_of_var='$val_of_var'"
    echo "Setting $name_of_var=$val_of_var"
    eval $cmd
    else
    echo "Using   $name_of_var=$val_of_var"
    fi
done

exec bundle exec unicorn $*
```

The `env` directory, and the files in it, can be added to your source control.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I can't give you an up vote yet because I don't have 15 rep, but I'll definitely come back when I do.

Answer (score 0):

Since asking the question, I've found this post from John Resig about a tip he learned from his coworker, Craig Silverstein.

http://ejohn.org/blog/keeping-passwords-in-source-control/

Instead of encrypting the keys into source control however, I will opt for his original solution of creating a dummy keys file that contains empty values, and storing the actual keys somewhere safe but accessible by my collaborators.